# Laptop Acer Aspire 3000 works normally just in safe mode of Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, safe-mode

Does onyone have any suggestion how to solve my problem, I did a fresh install of Windows XP to laptop and it works normally just in safe mode, if I boot in normal mode, it will start up, but right after it gets into windows it hangs, not totaly, cause if I run taskmanager I can see that CPU is busy at 70% all the time, but I am unable to get to process list, that I would see which process is keeping busy the CPU. I tried the msconfig and disabled all services and boot with diagnostic mode, but no success - what else could I do to figure out what is going on?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As it's a fresh install this is most likely a driver/bios/hardware issue,
try to install all the drivers in safe mode to see if this resolves the problem.

If this doesn't help, reset the BIOS, configure it right and try to install Windows again...

If it still occurs it's most likely to be hardware related and you will need to RMA or buy a new laptop.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer, I found out what was the problem and yes it's really a hardware issue, but just the battery, when I removed it, it started working ... that's all.